# clearing a UITextField when the user starts typing

Tags: ios, textfield, default

**short version**: How can I make a UITextField box remove all content on the users first keypress? I don't want the info removed until the user starts typing something. ie, clearing it on begin edit is not good enough.

**long version**: I have three UITextField that loop around (using the return key and catching the press in the "shouldReturn" method. There is text already in the UITextField, and if the user doesn't type anything and just goes to the next UITextField, the value should stay (default behaviour).

But I want it that if the user starts typing, it automatically clears the text first. Something like having the whole field highlighted, and then typing anything deletes the fiels and then adds the user keypress.

"Clear when editing begins" is no good, because the text is immediately cleared on the cursor appearing in the field. That's not desired. I thought I could use the placeholder here, but that doesn't work as a default, and I can't find a default value property. The Highlighted and Selected properties don't do anything in this regard either.

Comment: +1 for a well explained question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a `BOOL` variable in your `.h` file like.

```
BOOL clearField;
```

And implement the delegate methods like:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   clearField = YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  clearField = NO;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
  clearField = NO;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  if(clearField)
  {
     textField.text = @""
     clearField = NO;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, I just tried this and it ALMOST works perfectly for my situation. If I start typing, the field is cleared and my text populated - GOOD. But if I use the "NEXT" button on the keyboard and catch that in the ShouldRturn method, it doesn't clear the second field.

Comment: ok, solved it. I had the clearField below assigning the next responder (which essentially cleared it after it was set).

Comment: `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` doesn't return a BOOL?

Comment: @abbood: yes it'll surely return a bool. I just answered for his problem, writing the entire code is not my job. If he copy paste this code, his compiler will tell him, what he need to add in this

Answer (score 3):

There is a delegate method called

```
textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*) tf{
  tf.startedEdinting = YES;
}

textFeildDidEndEditing: (UITextField*) tf {
  tf.startedEditing = NO;
}
```

Add startEditing in a category to UITextField.

Then if value changes clear the field:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
 if (textField.startEditing){
  textField.text = string;
 } else {
  textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
 }
}
```

You can add the property to the UITextField category in the following way:

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL startEditing;
```

.m

```
@dynamic startEditing;

- (void) setStartEditing:(BOOL)startEditing_in{ 
NSNumber* num = [NSNumber numberWithBool:startEditing_in]; 
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, myConstant, num, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC); 
} 
- (BOOL) startEditing{ 
NSNumber* num = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, myConstant); 
return [num boolValue]; 
}
```

Comment: what is "startEditing" as far as the category is concerned? I'm figuring it can't be a property because they're not allowed in categories. But if it's a method, how do I define a variable to be used by both the getter and setter? I do understand the basic premise of a category, just not sure on how to use a variable between two methods of the category.

Comment: Dave, I would appreciate it if you could help me implement this. I tried doing it last night, but I'm getting stuck on how to implement my own property that can get shared across multiple methods (BTW, I didn'g give you the -1, I actually like your approach)

Comment: You can't use this approach. Categories can't add instance variables or properties, only methods. There is no way to add `startedEditing` to `UITextField`.

Comment: didn't think so, ahhh well.. I'm working on a subclassing method instead, but I'm stuck. I'll get there. Thanks

Comment: @rmaddy: You can add property in category. Please check it before downvoting my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520889/objective-c-categories-can-i-add-a-property-for-a-method-not-in-my-category The answer from Midhun MP is a better idea to solve the problem than my answer, but my answer can also solve the problem, so I don't think that downvoting my answer is ethic...

Comment: @Dave you can't add an ivar based property to a category. This solution can't be done as indicated.

Comment: @rmaddy: You can't add ivar based prop in category, but can add property without ivar. It's enough to solve the problem.

Comment: @Dave Without an ivar backing this property, how and where is the state to be kept? What's the implementation of the getter and setter methods for the property? You need to provide details on how you actually made this work.

Comment: @rmaddy: Here is your sample code: - (void) setStartEditing:(BOOL)startEditing_in{
    NSNumber* num = [NSNumber numberWithBool:startEditing_in];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, myConstant, num, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (BOOL) startEditing{
    NSNumber* num = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, myConstant);
    return [num boolValue];
}

Comment: Interesting. It would really help everyone if you updated your answer with this solution. The OP has asked you a couple of times for this.

Comment: Answer updated. I've never seen anywhere, that I was asked to do it. Where could I see it? I'm quite new at Stackoverflow.

Comment: See the first couple of comments (before mine) to your answer. BTW - the `@dynamic` isn't needed since you are providing the two methods in code.

Comment: @Dave Ok, thanks, I'm trying to get my head around this `objc_setAssociatedObject` thing. I actually very much like this answer, but want to consider: is this a hack (not being derogatory here) to the missing ability to having an ivar? Would this be considered poor or bad form?

Comment: @Madivad: Yes, it's a workaround for having an ivar in category. I have not faced with any issues about it.

Answer (score 2):

I want to thank people for their answers, I implemented both of the main methods described here and both worked flawlessly. But I have since come across a much simpler, nicer answer and involves only one line of code :)

In the textField's didBeginEditing method, place `[self.textField selectAll:self];` or `[self.textField selectAll:nil];`

The original answer I found had `selectAll:self` but this shows the cut/copy/paste menu. If you send `nil` instead of `self` the menu doesn't appear.

Adding this one line of code highlights the text on entering the textField (so gives the user a visual cue), and only removes everything once a key is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that fulfils the same purpose is by simply using a text field [placeholder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW14) which is defined as:

`The string that is displayed when there is no other text in the text field.`

So as soon as the user starts typing, the placeholder text disappears.

That's something you can set from the storyboard, or [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6529300/766570). (Yes it took me two hours trying to figure it the harder way.. when the solution was literally one line change of code).

Comment: G'day Abbood, thanks for your suggestion. I did think of this but this didn't really work as well. The problem being it cosmetically did exactly what I wanted (well, almost). The essential problem with this was that if the user doesn't end up putting something in the textfield then 'nothing' is returned. I realise this can be fixed programmatically but I was after a more elegant solution. If the placeholder could be used as a "default" of sorts that would do it.

Comment: fair enough.. but i thought this answer would be relevant in the context of your question (esp the short version).. let's put it this way: to someone who is totally new to uitext and text control in iOS, and googling something similar to your question title.. they'll land this page.. nothing is mentioned about placeholders on this page.. when it's clearly an answer to some who many not have the exact same need as you (Mindhun's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13417709/766570) may have solved your issue.. but it didn't solve mine)..

Comment: .. so i thought a `placeholder` merits at least a mention.. don't worry i'm not asking for a vote up or anything.. i just wanna write something that may save someone else some valuable time

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear the text one the user interacts with it, there is an option in interface builder to where you can set the text field to "Clear when editing begins."

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following method.

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string {  
  if(isFirsttime==YES)
{
textfield.text==@"";
isFirsttime=NO;
}
return YES;
     }
```

Comment: then youcan set a BOOL isFirsttime to YES and After first click make it NO and Use the above code (edited).

Comment: where have you declared/initialised "isFirttime"? And at what point do you set it to YES?

Comment: in `.h `file you can declare  `BOOL isFirsttime` and at `ViewdidLoad` set it to `YES` again in your `textfieldshouldreturn` method set it `YES`

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize a  NSString variable for your textField's initial text

```
NSString *initialText=@"initial text";
```

Then implement methods:

```
    -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
    if(textField.text isEqualToString:initialText)
         { 
           textField.text=@"";
        }
   }

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField.text isEqualToString:@"")
    {
        textField.text=initialText;
    }
}
```